# run and stop rake task from ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I already know that running a rake task from .rb file can be done by running:

```
system "/usr/bin/rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} > #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log"
```

But how to stop a currently running rake task from ruby file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do a

```
ps_aux = system "ps aux | grep #rake_task_name"
```

then, parse the pid. then, issue a kill command

```
system "kill #pid"
```

I haven't tried this yet though.

Answer (score 0):

From within the script, you could run the commands suggested by pat (parsing for the pid) in backticks, `system` or the `%x{}` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps afx | grep rake
```

Then kill the process id

```
kill -9 "process_id"
```

Comment: This does _not_ what the OP want. He asked to stop the task from Ruby.