# Set timeout to ruby Test::unit run

Tags: ruby, rake, testunit

I am using a rake task to run tests written in Ruby.
The rake task:

```
desc "This Run Tests on my ruby app"
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << File.dirname(__FILE__)
  t.test_files = FileList['test*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

I would like to create a timeout so that if any test (or the entire suite) hangs a timeout exception will be thrown and the test will fail.

I tried to create a new task that would run the test task with a timeout:

```
desc "Run Tests with timeout"
task :run_tests do
  Timeout::timeout(200) do
    Rake::Task['test'].invoke
  end
end
```

The result was that a timeout was thrown, but the test continued to run.

Comment: I don't know of a clean way to do this using only Ruby. You can wrap your `Timeout` call in a `begin`/`rescue` block to catch the exception it throws and use one of the `bash` solutions proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930157/run-and-stop-rake-task-from-ruby-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code adds a timeout for entire suite:

```
def self.suite
    mysuite = super
    def mysuite.run(*args)
        Timeout::timeout(600) do
            super
        end
    end
    mysuite
end
```

Comment: Where do you put it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something similar, and ended up writing this:

```
require 'timeout'

# Provides an individual timeout for every test.
#
# In general tests should run for less then 1s so 5s is quite a generous timeout.
#
# Timeouts can be overridden per-class (in rare cases where tests should take more time)
# by setting for example `self.test_timeout = 10 #s`
module TestTimeoutHelper
  def self.included(base)
    class << base
      attr_accessor :test_timeout
    end

    base.test_timeout = 5 # s
  end

  # This overrides the default minitest behaviour of measuring time, with extra timeout :)
  # This helps out with: (a) keeping tests fast :) (b) detecting infinite loops
  #
  # In general however benchmarks test should be used instead.
  # Timeout is very unreliable by the way but in general works.
  def time_it
    t0 = Minitest.clock_time

    Timeout.timeout(self.class.test_timeout, Timeout::Error, 'Test took to long (infinite loop?)') do
      yield
    end
  ensure
    self.time = Minitest.clock_time - t0
  end
end
```

This module should be included into either specific test cases, or a general test case.

It works with a MiniTest 5.x